# flask-js form.validate_on_submit() confirm() integration

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have a form to write changes after some values review. In `routes.py` I ensure the form is validated throug `.validate_on_submit()`:

```py
    ### ... rest of routes.py ....
    form = VariantOverallRevision()
    if form.validate_on_submit() :
        ### ... code to write new class on file ...
        flash("sent!")
    ### ... rest of routes.py ....
```

I want to insert a yes/no confirmation button through `js` in this submission, but I do not know how to integrate a "submission stop" after clicking.

I managed to integrate a `confirm()` in the button element, but apparently the form is sent as soon as the button is clicked (and not after the js `confirm()` is called):

```js
function confirm_ACMG_review()
{
    confirm("Save data?");
}
if (confirm_ACMG_review) {
    //proceed to sumbmission
}
else {
    //block submission
}
document.getElementById('manual_ACMG_annotation_confirm_review').onclick = confirm_ACMG_review;
```

Here the `HTML` section:

```html
        <form id="manual_ACMG_annotation_confirm_form" action="" method="post" novalidate>
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            {{ form.submit( id = "manual_ACMG_annotation_confirm_review", style = "font-size: 120%; font-weight: bold;" ) }}
        </form>
```

I know I could open a different page/redirect to other URL etc. , but I wanted to know if there is any method to intregrate flask submission with js.

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preventDefault()` method on click event so that the form isn't submitted by default.

```
document.getElementById("manual_ACMG_annotation_confirm_review").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault() // prevent default form submission
  // here you can implement confirmation
  // set confirm_ACMG_review value based on confirmation result
  if (confirm_ACMG_review) {
      document.getElementById('manual_ACMG_annotation_confirm_form').submit();  // submit form manually
  }
});
```